# Replace random string using sed

Tags: unix, sed

How do I replace random strings using sed. For example if I have a text file like this:

> EF125353.1 to be replaced 1
>
> EF125353.1 to be replaced again 2
>
> EF125353.1 to be replaced etc etc 3

And I would like to replace anything after **.1** till the end of the line with a space or with nothing to get a final file like this:

> EF125353.1
>
> EF125353.1
>
> EF125353.1

I am using Unix in OS X

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify: are all lines in the file looking like "EF<numbers>.<number> <other stuff>"? What exactly do you want? Find any lines with a '.1' and cut off everything after behind?

Comment: Also: Is EF125353.1 always the first word in the line?

Comment: Yes, all the lines start with EF and then follow by <number>.<number> <other rariable stuff> and I want to cut off everthing after the .<number>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your simple case my solution would be

```
cat file | cut -d' ' -f1
```

`-d' '` tells cut that the delimiter between fields is a space. `-f1` tells cut to keep the first column.

If you really want to use sed, which I would not suggest for this very simple case, you can do

```
cat file | sed -e 's/\.1.*/.1/'
```

`-e` is followed by the command to execute. `s/<search-string>/<replace-string>/` searches <search-string> and replaces it with <replace-string>. Search string is a regular expression. This means that `\.1.*` is interpreted as dot followed by '1' followed by any number ('*') of any characters ('.'). This will be replaced by '.1' (no need to escape here).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and my apologies for not clearly clarified my question. I have edited the question as above.

Comment: The second option worked perfectly. You are awesome. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use awk:

```
awk '{print $1}' input.txt > output.txt
```